# Invalid parameters error on createConversation in @google-cloud/contact-center-insights SDK

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to call **createConversation** function of CCAI insights SDK @google-cloud/contact-center-insights but getting below error

**ERROR ==> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.**

What would be the correct request payload? I'm not able to find sample request payload for this function.

I'm using below code:

```
 const [conversation] = await client.createConversation({
  parent: client.locationPath(projectId, 'us-central1'),  
  conversation: {
    medium: 'CHAT',
    name: 'TestModel',
    transcript: {
      transcriptSegments: [{
        segmentParticipant: {
          role: 'HUMAN_AGENT',
          userId: '1234'
        },
        text: 'Thank you for calling IBC, how can I help you today?',
        confidence: 0.90,
        sentiment: {
          magnitude: 0.2,
          score: 0.9
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
console.info(`Created `, conversation.name);
```

Note: It's working for below github code but I need to send the payload in transcript format.

[ccai-insight-github code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-contact-center-insights/blob/main/samples/createConversation.js)

And even if we store the conversation in Storage bucket, what would be the format?

Thanks

Comment: I tried this using Go (not NodeJS) and was able to get it working using GCS source per the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/contact-center/insights/docs/create-analyze-conversation-api). This describes the [CCAI Data Format](https://cloud.google.com/contact-center/insights/docs/conversation-data-format) which is what's used with e.g. `gs://cloud-samples-data/ccai/chat_sample.json`

Comment: [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) documents the [`create`](https://cloud.google.com/contact-center/insights/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.conversations/create) method and the [`Conversation`](https://cloud.google.com/contact-center/insights/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.conversations#Conversation) body and [`transcript`](https://cloud.google.com/contact-center/insights/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.conversations#Conversation.FIELDS.transcript) is output only and so can't be used (as part of the request body).

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin. yeah I see it's working with GCS. I was looking for sending chat in transcript as parameters but looks like that is not supported.

Comment: Yes, it's poorly documented but I was only able to get it to work using GCS.